# Does WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 supports Manager/Worker cluster deployment pattern

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

WSO2 Documentation found [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+Identity+Server) describes that WSO2 Identity Server based on Carbon 4.2.X does not support Manager/Worker deployment pattern. However, WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 was just released and it is based on Carbon 4.4.X. Can I assume that this version supports this deployment pattern? If so is the configuration the same as other products based on Carbon 4.4.x? The documentation does not seems to be updated against this new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, There was a shortcoming in the docs and it is fixed now. You can follow guide at [1]. WSO2 IS doesn't need the worker/manager separation as it is not hosting any artifacts like other servers. For further details read [2]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+Identity+Server+5.1.0

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Separating+the+Worker+and+Manager+Nodes